# Javascript how to get an array depth

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Array like this:

```
const array = [
  {
    title: 'xx',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'xxx',
        children: [
           { title: 'xxx' }
        ]
      }        
    ]
  }
]
```

The depth is 3, how i get depth use a function, or make array become this

```js
const array = [
  {
    title: 'xx',
    depth: 1,
    children: [
      {
        title: 'xxx',
        depth: 2,
        children: [
           { title: 'xxx', depth: 3 }
        ]
      }        
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a better way in javascript?

Comment: Which is it you want; the depth or to alter the array? Have you tried anything that you're having trouble with?

Comment: As per @Phil, showing a data structure and no real code is just that, an absence of a coding attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple recursive function to decorate the children at each level.

```js
const array = [
  {
    title: 'Title 1',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Title 2',
        children: [
           { 
             title: 'Title 3' 
           }
        ]
      }        
    ]
  }
];

const depthArray = depthDecorator(array);
console.log(depthArray);

function depthDecorator(array, depth = 1) {
  return array.map((child) => Object.assign(child, { 
    depth, 
    children: depthDecorator(child.children || [], depth + 1)
  }));
}
```

Comment: Would definitely help with displaying a tree on UI level